# fetch data from api loading slow react native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am fetching data(content and image) from an api, and render it to a flatlist, whenever I load the app it is always slow and take a while before it display the rendered data, how can I fix it, I will appreciate if you work on my code, to provide the answer and also if you will recommend a dependency make sure it work with **expo** see my below code.

```
    URL = 'https://placewave.com/avatar';

    const [Data, setData] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://placewave.com/alluser')
        .then((response) => setData(response.data))
        .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
    }, []);


<FlatList 
   data = {Data}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator = {false}  
   renderItem={({item}) => {
    return (


    <Image 
     source={{ uri: URL + '/' + item.user_image}}
     resizeMode="cover"
     style={styles.userImage}
    />
   <Text>{item.user_name}</Text>

   )
}}
/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: If response has huge data then It will take time to render on screen and other thing is, If images are too heavy then It will also take time to render

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned by Nooruddin there a few reasons. As your app does not show anything until the list of all users and at least the first image is loaded this seems to be the reason.

A few improvements:

- show a loading indicator until at least the user list is loaded (`ActivityIndicator`)
- if the API supports this, try to load the users in blocks (like 20 per fetch) and implement a load more with the `onScroll`-Event of `FlatList`
- if the API supports this, load thumbnails of the user images in overview mode and only full resolution if needed.